# How can I specify the path to redirect requests from apache2 to a tomcat worker node using mod_jk?

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, tomcat9, mod-jk, apache2-module

I need to specify the path to redirect requests from the apache2 server to the tomcat worker node.

There was a need to balance the load using mod_jk. Before that, ProxyPass was configured:

```
/api {HOST}:{PORT}/{APP}/api
```

Now I need to implement the path through mod_jk.

JkMount allows redirect /api to a worker ({HOST}:{PORT}), but will not allow specify the further part of the path.

Is it possible to do this at all, and if possible, where should I write the further path of the request?